# web component test mocha/chai/playwright (web test runner from modern-web): Tests were interrupted because the page was reloaded

Tags: testing, mocha.js, web-component, chai, playwright

I am evaluating the web-test-runner with playwright from modern-web (https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) to test my web-components.

My sample project is the following:

./package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "web-test-runner \"**/*.test.html\" \"**/*.test.js\" --node-resolve --playwright --browsers chromium firefox webkit --coverage",
    "test:watch": "web-test-runner \"**/*.test.html\" \"**/*.test.js\" --node-resolve --playwright --browsers chromium firefox webkit --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@esm-bundle/chai": "^4.1.5",
    "@web/test-runner": "^0.10.0",
    "@web/test-runner-playwright": "^0.6.6"
  }
}
```

./my-component/my-component.js

```js
(async() => {

  const res = await fetch('/my-component/my-component.html');
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = await res.text();

  class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }

  window.customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
  })();
```

./my-component/my-component.html

```html
<style>
    h2 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
```

./my-component/test/my-component.test.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="/my-component/my-component.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="module">
        import { runTests } from '@web/test-runner-mocha';
        import { expect } from '@esm-bundle/chai';

        let element;
        runTests(async () => {
            describe('HTML tests', () => {
                beforeEach(() => {
                    element = document.createElement("my-component");
                    document.body.appendChild(element);
                });
                afterEach(() => {
                    document.body.removeChild(element);
                });
                it('component is loaded', () => {
                    expect(element.shadowRoot).to.exist;
                });
                it('component contains h2 with text', () => {
                    expect(element.shadowRoot.querySelector('h2').innerHTML).to.equal('Hello world!');
                });
                it('component is displayed in red color', () => {
                    const el = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('h2');
                    expect(getComputedStyle(el)).to.have.property('color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this test is passing successfully.

according to modern-web documentation, it is also possible to create tests within js files. So, I am trying with this test:

./my-component/test/my-component.test.js

```js
import { runTests } from '@web/test-runner-mocha';
import { expect } from '@esm-bundle/chai';

let element;
runTests(async () => {
    describe('HTML tests', () => {
        before(() => {
            const script = document.createElement("script");
            script.setAttribute("src", "/my-component/my-component.js");
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        });
        beforeEach(() => {
            element = document.createElement("my-component");
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        });
        afterEach(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(element);
        });
        it('component is loaded', () => {
            expect(element.shadowRoot).to.exist;
        });
        it('component contains h2 with text', () => {
            expect(element.shadowRoot.querySelector('h2').innerHTML).to.equal('Hello world!');
        });
        it('component is displayed in red color', () => {
            const el = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('h2');
            expect(getComputedStyle(el)).to.have.property('color', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
        });
    });
});
```

This is basically the same as for the html test with the addition of the before directive to register my component script.

When running the js test, I get this error:

```
my-component/test/my-component.test.js:

 ❌ Tests were interrupted because the page was reloaded. This can happen when clicking a link, submitting a form or interacting with window.location.

Chromium: |██████████████████████████████| 1/1 test files | 0 passed, 0 failed
Firefox:  |██████████████████████████████| 1/1 test files | 0 passed, 0 failed
Webkit:   |██████████████████████████████| 1/1 test files | 0 passed, 0 failed

View full coverage report at coverage/lcov-report/index.html
```

How could I solve it?

Best Regards,